# Clear command is not deleting messages correctly discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a bulk-clear command for my bot. I tried this code:

```js
            await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: args[0] }).then(messages => {
                message.channel.send(`Deleting Messages...`).then(msg => {
                    setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 500)
                })
                message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
            });
```

But it doesn't work correctly. when I run `!clear 3`, It deletes 2 messages.

- Notes: I am using discord.js v13 and node.js v16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your bot also counts your command as a message, and removes it. That's why it only removes 2 other messages. To prevent that you will have to add a filter or remove your command first using `message.delete()`
2. [`Channel.bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) is not removing messages that are older than 2 weeks by default! To enable `filterOld` parameter you'll have to use `Channel.bulkDelete(number, true)` and you'll be able to delete these messages as well!

Answer (score -2):

First of all, your command is a message thats why it deletes less that the amount
Second of all, bots cannot delete messages that are older than 2 weeks
third of all, you cannot delete more than 100 messages.
so you can do:

```js
const amount = args[0]

if (amount > 100 || amount < 1) {
 return message.channel.send({content: `I cannot delete 100 messages or more`})
        }
const messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch({
            limit: amount + 1,
        }); 
await message.channel.bulkDelete(messages, true)
```